# I am trying to write an algorithm that uses a stack to check if an expression has balanced parentheses but I keep encountering this error

Tags: python, stack, parentheses

```
def is_matched(expression):
    left_bracket = "[({"
    right_bracket = "])}"
    my_stack = Stack(len(expression))
    # our solution methodology is to go through the expression and push all of the the open brackets onto the stack and then
    # with the closing brackets - each time we encounter a closing bracket we will pop the stack and compare
    for character in expression:
        if character in left_bracket:
            my_stack.push(character)
        elif character in right_bracket:
            # first check to see that the stack is not empty i.e we actually have some opneing brackets in the expression
            if my_stack.is_empty():
                return False
                # now we need to check that the type of braket we pop is the equivalent of it's closing bracket in the expression
            if right_bracket.index(character) != left_bracket.index(my_stack.pop):
                return False
    return my_stack.is_empty()

print(is_matched("()"))
```

```
    if right_bracket.index(character) != left_bracket.index(my_stack.pop):
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
python-BaseException
```

here is my stack implementation:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        """Builds a stack with given capacity > 0."""
        if capacity <= 0:
            raise Exception("The capacity must be positive")
        self.the_array = [None] * capacity
        self.top = -1  # the index of the top element

    def size(self):
        """Returns the size, i.e. the number
        of elements in the container."""
        return self.top + 1

    def is_empty(self):
        """Returns True if and only if the container is empty."""
        return self.size() == 0

    def is_full(self):
        """Returns True if and only if the container is full."""
        return self.size() >= len(self.the_array)

    def push(self, item):
        """Places the given item at the top of the stack
        if there is capacity, or raises an Exception."""
        if self.is_full():
            raise Exception("The stack is full")
        self.top += 1
        self.the_array[self.top] = item

    def pop(self):
        """Removes and returns the top element of the stack,
        or raises an Exception if there is none."""
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception("The stack is empty")
        item = self.the_array[self.top]
        # removes a reference to this item,
        # helps with memory management and debugging
        self.the_array[self.top] = None
        self.top -= 1
        return item

    def reset(self):
        """Removes all elements from the container."""
        while not self.is_empty():
            self.pop()
        assert (self.is_empty)
```

It should upon the second iteration pop the stack and notice that the indexes of the right and left bracket are the same and move into the final iteration where it realises the stack is empty and returns True but it is not doing so but instead throwing a typeError.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you mean to call pop like, `my_stack.pop()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at this line:

`if right_bracket.index(character) != left_bracket.index(my_stack.pop):`

you actually need to call `pop` method, since `pop` is a method, not a property.

therefore it should look like this:

`if right_bracket.index(character) != left_bracket.index(my_stack.pop()):`

Comment: omg thank you so much - I knew it was something trivial ugh

Comment: @Evs if it works for you I'd appreciate if you can accept my answer. Thanks